# fancyhdr is the same for even and odd pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books

I'm trying to have different headers and footers for even and odd pages using `fancyhdr`.

- For even pages headers, I want on the left to be the chapter title and on the right the section I'm in
- For odd pages headers, I want on the left to be the name of the author title and on the right the title of the document
- For all pages footers, just the page number at the right

I've tried everything using that package but no matter the option I write on `\fancyhead` or `\fancyfoot`, the header is the same on every page.

This is what I have achieved for now

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, removing the oneside option makes even pages to have a smaller `layouthoffset` and are closer to the left side of the page. Is there a way to not use oneside option and make even and odd pages to be centered?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  % Dimensiones del papel

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}         % Para usar el español
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sidenotes} % Notas en el margen de la página
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment} 
Podemos usar para incluir imágenes:

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{This is in the margin.}%
\end{marginfigure}

O simplemente texto

\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}                       % Para los gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}                 % Para matrices hechas con tikz
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}              % Para unir nodos hechos con tikz

\usepackage{color}                        % Colores 
\usepackage{siunitx}                     % Utilidades de medida del sistema internacional
\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Para evitar aliasing en elementos usados con siunitx
\usepackage{mathtools}                % Para las matrices por ejemplo
\usepackage{amsmath}                 % Conjunto de herramientas para modo matemático
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz} % Circuitos electrónicos
\usepackage{enumerate}               % Enumeraciones
\usepackage{amssymb}                 % Símbolos

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Para usar una página en blanco %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{Prueba de acceso a la universidad}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}} % Cambiamos el nombre del capítulo a tema

\usepackage{cancel}                 % Tachar elementos con una línea
\usepackage{float}                    % Floats para posiciones de las imágenes
\usepackage{courier}                % Letra Courier

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % Definiciones de colores para usar con textcolor

\definecolor{arylideyellow1}{RGB}{255,255,150}

\pagecolor{arylideyellow1}          % Color de la página
\usepackage{afterpage}            % Usamos \afterpage{\nopagecolor} después de la página que  no queramos color     
\usepackage{bm}                      % Matemáticas en negrita

\usepackage{enumitem}            % Para cambiar las enumeraciones (letras y números)
\usepackage{multicol}               % Múltiples columnas

%%%%% Redefinición de la macro del capítulo para la separación entre titulo y la sección

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Para usar una página en blanco %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-2}%
    \newpage}
% Usamos  \afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Título del libro %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter                    
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{0\p@} % Espacio entre el inicio de la página y el título del capítulo
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@  % Espacio entre el número del capítulo y el título del capítulo
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@ % Espacio entre el título del capítulo y el título de la sección
}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        tbd
    \end{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{a4paper,  % Geometría real del documento
        centering, 
        layoutwidth=20cm,
        layoutheight = 34cm,
        layoutvoffset = -2.5cm,
        layouthoffset = -1cm
    }
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{Conceptos básicos}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \section{Multiplicación de números}
    Cuando tenemos dos números cualesquiera $ a $ y $ b $ y tenemos que multiplicarlos simplemente escribimos:
    \[
    a\cdot b = c
    \]
    donde $ c $ es el resultado de multiplicar estos dos números. Vamos a tener en cuenta que:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son positivos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ (+\cdot+=+) $
        \item Si $ a $ es positivo y $ b $ es negativo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ (+\cdot-=-) $
        \item Si $ a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ (-\cdot+=-) $
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son negativos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ (-\cdot-=+) $
    \end{itemize}
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ 5\cdot 2=10 $
        \item $ 5\cdot(-2)=-10 $
        \item $ (-5)\cdot2=-10 $
        \item $ (-5)\cdot(-2)=10 $
    \end{itemize}
    Imaginemos una multiplicación de números en donde $ -a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo. El resultado entonces será negativo $ (-\cdot+=-) $
    \[
    -a\cdot b= -c
    \]
    El signo $ - $ de delante de $ a $ se puede poner aparte como un $ -1 $ que está multiplicando tanto a $ a $ como a $ b $:
    \[
    -a\cdot b= -c \longrightarrow (-1)\cdot a\cdot b= -c
    \]
    Y como en una multiplicación de dos números (o más) da igual el orden en el que multipliquemos los números, debido a la propiedad de la multiplicación $ a\cdot b = b\cdot a $. Es igualmente válido escribir la múltipliación anterior de la siguiente forma:
    \[
    (-1)\cdot a\cdot b=a\cdot(-1)\cdot b = a\cdot b \cdot (-1)=b\cdot a\cdot(-1)= b\cdot(-1)\cdot a
    \]
    Todas estas formas de escribir la ecuación tendrán como resultado $ -c $\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    {\bfseries\underline{Dvisión de números (fracciones)}}\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    Cuando tenemos dos números cualesquiera $ a $ y $ b $ y tenemos que dividirlos simplemente escribimos:
    \[
    \frac{a}{b}=c
    \]
    donde $ c $ es el resulatdo de dividir estos dos números. Vamos a tener en cuenta que:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son positivos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ \left(\dfrac{+}{+}=+\right) $

        \item Si $ a $ es positivo y $ b $ es negativo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{+}{-}=-\right) $
        \item Si $ a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{+}=- \right)$
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son negativos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{-}=+\right) $
    \end{itemize}
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ \dfrac{10}{2}=5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{10}{-2}=-5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{-10}{2}=-5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{-10}{-2}=5 $
    \end{itemize}
    Imaginemos una división de números en donde $ -a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo. El resultado entonces será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{+}=-\right) $
    \[
    \frac{-a}{b}=-c
    \]
    Y, como en la multiplicación, el signo $ - $ de delante de $ a $ se puede poner aparte como un $ -1 $ que está multiplicando a $ a $:
    \[
    \frac{-a}{b}=-c\longrightarrow \frac{(-1)\cdot a}{b}=-c
    \]
    En totalmente válido escribir 
    \[
    \frac{(-1)\cdot a}{b}
    \]
    que
    \[
    \frac{a}{(-1)\cdot b}
    \]
    que 
    \[
    -\frac{a}{b}
    \]
    Las tres formas de escribir la ecuación tienen el mismo significado.\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    Las parte de arriba de una fracción se llama \textit{numerador} y la parte de abajo \textit{denominador}.
    \[
    \text{Fracción}=\frac{\text{Numerador}}{\text{Denominador}}
    \]
    En nuestro ejemplo, $ a $ es el numerador y $ b $ es el denominador. Supongamos que tenemos un número que multiplica al numerador, llamado $ k $ y un número que multiplica al denominador llamado $ h $. Entonces podemos escribir:
    \[
    \frac{k\cdot a}{h\cdot b}
    \]
    Si $ k=h $, podemos "tacharlos" del numerador y del denominador, haciendo que la ecuación sea:
    \[
    \frac{k\cdot a}{h\cdot b} \underbrace{=}_{k=h}\frac{a}{b}
    \]
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ \dfrac{2\cdot 5}{2\cdot 3}=\dfrac{5}{3} $
        \item $ \dfrac{8\cdot 10}{8\cdot 5}=\dfrac{10}{5} $
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try without the `oneside` documentclass option if you want different headers on even and odd pages

Comment: `\documentclass[oneside]{book}` specifies that you want odd and even pages to have the same style.

Comment: @samcarter But then, even pages have a smaller `layouthoffset ` and are closer to the left side of the page.

Comment: @Martín Yes, a two sided document normally includes a binding offset. If you don't like it, set `bindingoffset` to zero in the geometry settings. Also margins are asymmetrical by default, but they can also be adjusted.

Comment: @samcarter I've written `bindingoffset=0cm` inside `\newgeometry` just after the title and nothing changed :(

Comment: @Martín: Try with the `hcentering` option (untested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was preparing this answer, the OP posted his.  Maybe, however, that the following example of how to get a twosided document, with different headers on odd and even pages, but with the text area centered between the margins, is still valuable because of its terseness:

```
% The "article" class will do:
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not essential
\usepackage[textwidth=13cm,hcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example, generates "Lorem ipsum" dummy text

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{Sample text sample text}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-32]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @koleygr in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470951/158817), the problem was fixed for both this question and the one in the link. To have a different geometry in the title page, simply add `\newgeometry{a4paper,centering}` and then `\restoregeometry` to use the defined geometry of the book.

Here is the full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[centering, 
layoutwidth=20cm,
layouthoffset = -0.5cm,
layoutheight = 34cm,
layoutvoffset = -2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}         % Para usar el español
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sidenotes} % Notas en el margen de la página
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment} 
Podemos usar para incluir imágenes:

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{This is in the margin.}%
\end{marginfigure}

O simplemente texto

\end{comment}

\title{\huge \bfseries Apuntes prueba de acceso a mayores de 25 años}           % Título
\author{Martín Mateos Sánchez}
\date{}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tikz}                       % Para los gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}                 % Para matrices hechas con tikz
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}              % Para unir nodos hechos con tikz

\usepackage{color}                        % Colores 
\usepackage{siunitx}                     % Utilidades de medida del sistema internacional
\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Para evitar aliasing en elementos usados con siunitx
\usepackage{mathtools}                % Para las matrices por ejemplo
\usepackage{amsmath}                 % Conjunto de herramientas para modo matemático
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz} % Circuitos electrónicos
\usepackage{enumerate}               % Enumeraciones
\usepackage{amssymb}                 % Símbolos

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               % Headers y Footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{The performance of new graduates}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{Hola}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}} % Cambiamos el nombre del capítulo a tema

\usepackage{cancel}                 % Tachar elementos con una línea
\usepackage{float}                    % Floats para posiciones de las imágenes
\usepackage{courier}                % Letra Courier

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % Definiciones de colores para usar con textcolor

\definecolor{arylideyellow1}{RGB}{255,255,150}

\pagecolor{arylideyellow1}          % Color de la página
\usepackage{afterpage}            % Usamos \afterpage{\nopagecolor} después de la página que  no queramos color     
\usepackage{bm}                      % Matemáticas en negrita

\usepackage{enumitem}            % Para cambiar las enumeraciones (letras y números)
\usepackage{multicol}               % Múltiples columnas

%%%%% Redefinición de la macro del capítulo para la separación entre titulo y la sección

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Para usar una página en blanco %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-2}%
    \newpage}
% Usamos  \afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Título del libro %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter                    
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{0\p@} % Espacio entre el inicio de la página y el título del capítulo
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@  % Espacio entre el número del capítulo y el título del capítulo
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@ % Espacio entre el título del capítulo y el título de la sección
}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{a4paper,centering}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        Hola
    \end{titlepage}
    \restoregeometry

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{Conceptos básicos}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \section{Multiplicación de números}
    Cuando tenemos dos números cualesquiera $ a $ y $ b $ y tenemos que multiplicarlos simplemente escribimos:
    \[
    a\cdot b = c
    \]
    donde $ c $ es el resultado de multiplicar estos dos números. Vamos a tener en cuenta que:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son positivos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ (+\cdot+=+) $
        \item Si $ a $ es positivo y $ b $ es negativo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ (+\cdot-=-) $
        \item Si $ a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ (-\cdot+=-) $
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son negativos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ (-\cdot-=+) $
    \end{itemize}
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ 5\cdot 2=10 $
        \item $ 5\cdot(-2)=-10 $
        \item $ (-5)\cdot2=-10 $
        \item $ (-5)\cdot(-2)=10 $
    \end{itemize}
    Imaginemos una multiplicación de números en donde $ -a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo. El resultado entonces será negativo $ (-\cdot+=-) $
    \[
    -a\cdot b= -c
    \]
    El signo $ - $ de delante de $ a $ se puede poner aparte como un $ -1 $ que está multiplicando tanto a $ a $ como a $ b $:
    \[
    -a\cdot b= -c \longrightarrow (-1)\cdot a\cdot b= -c
    \]
    Y como en una multiplicación de dos números (o más) da igual el orden en el que multipliquemos los números, debido a la propiedad de la multiplicación $ a\cdot b = b\cdot a $. Es igualmente válido escribir la múltipliación anterior de la siguiente forma:
    \[
    (-1)\cdot a\cdot b=a\cdot(-1)\cdot b = a\cdot b \cdot (-1)=b\cdot a\cdot(-1)= b\cdot(-1)\cdot a
    \]
    Todas estas formas de escribir la ecuación tendrán como resultado $ -c $\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    {\bfseries\underline{Dvisión de números (fracciones)}}\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    Cuando tenemos dos números cualesquiera $ a $ y $ b $ y tenemos que dividirlos simplemente escribimos:
    \[
    \frac{a}{b}=c
    \]
    donde $ c $ es el resulatdo de dividir estos dos números. Vamos a tener en cuenta que:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son positivos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ \left(\dfrac{+}{+}=+\right) $
        \item Si $ a $ es positivo y $ b $ es negativo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{+}{-}=-\right) $
        \item Si $ a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo, el número $ c $ será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{+}=- \right)$
        \item Si $ a $ y $ b $ son negativos, el número $ c $ será positivo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{-}=+\right) $
    \end{itemize}
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ \dfrac{10}{2}=5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{10}{-2}=-5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{-10}{2}=-5 $
        \item $ \dfrac{-10}{-2}=5 $
    \end{itemize}
    Imaginemos una división de números en donde $ -a $ es negativo y $ b $ es positivo. El resultado entonces será negativo $ \left(\dfrac{-}{+}=-\right) $
    \[
    \frac{-a}{b}=-c
    \]
    Y, como en la multiplicación, el signo $ - $ de delante de $ a $ se puede poner aparte como un $ -1 $ que está multiplicando a $ a $:
    \[
    \frac{-a}{b}=-c\longrightarrow \frac{(-1)\cdot a}{b}=-c
    \]
    En totalmente válido escribir 
    \[
    \frac{(-1)\cdot a}{b}
    \]
    que
    \[
    \frac{a}{(-1)\cdot b}
    \]
    que 
    \[
    -\frac{a}{b}
    \]
    Las tres formas de escribir la ecuación tienen el mismo significado.\vspace{0.2cm}\\
    Las parte de arriba de una fracción se llama \textit{numerador} y la parte de abajo \textit{denominador}.
    \[
    \text{Fracción}=\frac{\text{Numerador}}{\text{Denominador}}
    \]
    En nuestro ejemplo, $ a $ es el numerador y $ b $ es el denominador. Supongamos que tenemos un número que multiplica al numerador, llamado $ k $ y un número que multiplica al denominador llamado $ h $. Entonces podemos escribir:
    \[
    \frac{k\cdot a}{h\cdot b}
    \]
    Si $ k=h $, podemos "tacharlos" del numerador y del denominador, haciendo que la ecuación sea:
    \[
    \frac{k\cdot a}{h\cdot b} \underbrace{=}_{k=h}\frac{a}{b}
    \]
    \underline{Ejemplo}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ \dfrac{2\cdot 5}{2\cdot 3}=\dfrac{5}{3} $
        \item $ \dfrac{8\cdot 10}{8\cdot 5}=\dfrac{10}{5} $
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```